# Create trigger to run procedure to check limits

Tags: mysql

So what im trying to do is to check if variables are within range. Basically i have sensors that measure something (measure_Variable) so for exaple sensorID:1 is measuring temperature, sensorID:2 is measuring humidity etc.

I have another table for records where sensors post data.
I have one more table which is measure_type. Over there are stored the limits. What i want to do is to check the value of the record, and if its within the limits then update table validity column record_validity with 1. Else update with 0.

I've created a procedure which kinda works but I cannot pass the value to the other table called validity.

`SELECT recordId,value,measure_variable,limit_min,limit_max FROM records,sensors,measure_type WHERE records.value BETWEEN measure_type.limit_min AND measure_type.limit_max GROUP BY(records.recordId)`

Any ideas would be highly appreciated!

[DB_Schema_Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0rqi.png)

Comment: This is excess and unneeded work. Save raw sensors data without any addition and/or modifying. Calculate your validity value in the query when you need in it.

Comment: @Akina yes, this goes against the textbook version of normalisation. However, in certain cases denormalisation can be a great optimisation technique. Sensor recordings are not going to change and I can see how record_validity field can be used in various queries as a filter criteria. Thus a materialised field as part of other indexes can be used to speed up queries.

Comment: @legoz: can you pls add some sample data for the affected tables and some sample output? Otherwise we will struggle with coming up with a solution! I would also consider if you want to implement this as a trigger, or calculate the value as part of the insert statement (insert ... select ... statement can combine literal values with values taken from other tables)

Comment: @Shadow In systems for recording the data obtained from sensors, the speed of saving is most often critical parameter. And any additional operation during this process is unwanted. Even partitioning by the data correctness (indirect, of course - a partition for correct values and 2 partitions for the values below / above) can be preferable.

Comment: @Akina we do not know anything about the the frequency of the inserts, nor how critical it is to record every single observation, so we do not know how critical the speed of recording the observation is to the OP. However, dismissing an optimisation technique without understanding  the business case for it is surely a bad advice.

Comment: @Shadow In such case I'd prefer generated column rather than one calculated in the trigger.

Comment: @Akina a generated column cannot use values from another table.

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys. Appreciate it. The main idea behind this question is to check whether a record is within the appropriate range. For example if the temperature sensor has to operate from 0-40 degrees, if i receive a record of 88 its obviously false. So i want to check the range and somehow be notified that a specific record is invalid so i go and check the sensor.

Comment: Moreover, one sensor can measure multiple things. For example i might have a sensor to measure temperature, humidity, wind speed. Therefore i want to look all the parameters if they are within range.

Comment: *Moreover, one sensor can measure multiple things. For example i might have a sensor to measure temperature, humidity, wind speed. Therefore i want to look all the parameters if they are within range.* Does the ranges for the same parameter got from different sensors may differ?